# Nativescript radListView unable to get item by id

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Hi I am using {N} with angular2
and getting below error when accessing view by Id in from RadListView

```
<RadListView id="listView" [items]="posts" loadOnDemandMode="Manual" scrollDirection="Vertical"
             itemInsertAnimation="Fade" itemDeleteAnimation="Fade"
             (loadMoreDataRequested)="onLoadMoreItemsRequested($event)">
    <template tkListItemTemplate let-post="item">
        <CardView id="post-{{ post.kl_id }}" margin="8 0 8 0" elevation="15" class="whiteCard" shadowOffsetHeight="3" shadowOffsetWidth="1">
            <Label (tap)="doSomethingWithPost(post)"></Label>
        </CardView>
    </template>
</RadListView>
```

In my Component

```
let view = require("ui/core/view");
doSomethingWithPost(post){
 let postGridLayout = view.getViewById(this.page, "post-" + post.kl_id);
}
```

I am getting below error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'value.view.itemView')
```

Answer (score 0):

use viewChild

```
@ViewChild(/* id like*/ 'foo') myElement: ElementRef;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    let myfoo= this.myElement
}
```

Comment: Hi Habib the id is dynamic and its in loop, here my goal is to delete the item(CardView) from view when tap on the particular item and getting  it by Id.. The above is code working fine for ListtView and not working for 'RadListView'

Comment: so try this one add an variable <CardView #myVar ></CardView > and pass it like this  doSomethingWithPost(post,myVar)